# Can the C preprocessor be used to tell if a file exists?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

I have a very large codebase (read: thousands of modules) that has code shared across numerous projects that all run on different operating systems with different C++ compilers. Needless to say, maintaining the build process can be quite a chore.

There are several places in the codebase where it would clean up the code substantially if only there were a way to make the pre-processor ignore certain `#includes` if the file didn't exist in the current folder. Does anyone know a way to achieve that?

Presently, we use an `#ifdef` around the `#include` in the shared file, with a second project-specific file that #defines whether or not the `#include` exists in the project. This works, but it's ugly. People often forget to properly update the definitions when they add or remove files from the project. I've contemplated writing a pre-build tool to keep this file up to date, but if there's a platform-independent way to do this with the preprocessor I'd much rather do it that way instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Generally this is done by using a script that tries running the preprocessor on an attempt at including the file. Depending on if the preprocessor returns an error, the script updates a generated .h file with an appropriate #define (or #undef). In bash, the script might look vaguely like this:

```
cat > .test.h <<'EOM'
#include <asdf.h>
EOM
if gcc -E .test.h
 then
  echo '#define HAVE_ASDF_H 1' >> config.h
 else 
  echo '#ifdef HAVE_ASDF_H' >> config.h
  echo '# undef HAVE_ASDF_H' >> config.h
  echo '#endif' >> config.h
 fi
```

A pretty thorough framework for portably working with portability checks like this (as well as thousands others) is [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Answer (score 130):

## Little Update

Some compilers might support `__has_include ( header-name )`.

The extension was added to the [C++17 standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) ([P0061R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0061r1.html)).

### Compiler Support

- Clang
- GCC from 5.X
- Visual Studio from VS2015 Update 2 (?)

### Example (from clang website):

```
// Note the two possible file name string formats.
#if __has_include("myinclude.h") && __has_include(<stdint.h>)
# include "myinclude.h"
#endif
```

## Sources

- [SD-6: SG10 Feature Test Recommendations](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations)
- [Clang Language Extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#langext-has-include)

Comment: This will be part of C++17! https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html

Comment: If I'm interpreting the [WG14 minutes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2142.pdf) correctly, this feature [will also be](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2101.htm) added to C2X.

Comment: Useful in Objective-C to test for conditional presence of other libraries/components in iOS (looking at you React Native)

Comment: I guess this is the end for standard "configure" unix/linux tool - compiler by itself provides mechanism to query if we have specific header or not. :-D

Comment: `__has_include` is already in the C2x draft: https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3054.pdf

Answer (score 58):

Create a special folder for missing headers, and make that folder to be searched last
*(that is compliler specific - last item in "INCLUDES" environment variable, something like that)*

Then if some header1.h can be missing, create in that folder a stub

header1.h:

```
#define header1_is_missing
```

Now you can always write

```
#include <header1.h>
#ifdef header1_is_missing

   // there is no header1.h 

#endif
```

Comment: +1 for making the source code itself fully portable, and shifting the portability burden onto the compiler invocation itself (which is already necessarily approximately non-portable between different compilers).

Comment: I guess more precisely, not just making the source code fully portable, but also *ready to compile as-is* (assuming the right options, and possibly even without any special options in some cases).

Answer (score 11):

The preprocessor itself cannot identify the existence of files but you certainly can use the build environment to do so.  I'm mostly familiar with make, which would allow you to do something like this in your makefile:

```
ifdef $(test -f filename && echo "present")
  DEFINE=-DFILENAME_PRESENT
endif
```

Of course, you'd have to find an analog to this in other build environments like VisualStudio, but I'm sure they exist.

Comment: +1 for making the source code itself fully portable. I think this (or rather in my typical cases a modification where the file is assumed to exist by default and people can signal if they don't have the file) might even be my most preferred method of the ones I see here, because it's trivial to document the defines, and the typical user building from source can already be expected to know or easily figure out how to define pre-processor variables in their specific build system or compiler.

Comment: I guess more precisely, not just making the source code fully portable, but also *ready to compile as-is* (assuming the right pre-processor defines, and possibly even without any special options in some cases).

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility: populate a directory somewhere with zero-length versions of all of the headers you wish to optionally include. Pass a -I argument to this directory as the *last* such option.

The GCC cpp searches its include directories in order, if it finds a header file in an earlier directory it will use it. Otherwise, it will eventually find the zero-length file, and be happy.

I presume that other cpp implementations also search their include directories in the order specified.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a pre-build step run that generates an include file that contains a list of #defines that represent the names of the files existing in the current directory:

```
#define EXISTS_FILE1_C
#define EXISTS_FILE1_H
#define EXISTS_FILE2_C
```

Then, include that file from within your source code, and then your source can test the `EXISTS_*` defines to see whether a file exists or not.

Answer (score 4):

So far as I know cpp does not have a directive regarding the existence of a file.

You might be able to accomplish this with a bit of help from the Makefile, if you're using the same make across platforms. You can detect the presence of a file in the Makefile:

```
foo.o: foo.c
    if [ -f header1.h ]; then CFLAGS+=-DHEADER1_INC
```

As @Greg Hewgill mentions, you can then make your #includes be conditional:

```
#ifdef HEADER1_INC
#include <header1.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to some claims here and on the internet, Visual Studio 2015 does NOT support the `__has_include` feature - at least according to my experience. Tested with Update 3.

The rumors may have arisen from the fact that VS 2017 is also referred to as "Version 15"; VS 2015 is instead referred to as "Version 14". Support for the feature seems to have been officially introduced with "Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3".

Answer (score 1):

**I had to do something similar for the Symbian OS. This is how i did it:
lets say you want to check if the file "file_strange.h" exists and you want to include some headers or link to some libraries depending on the existance of that file.**

**first creat a small batch file for checking the existence of that file.**

autoconf is good but an over kill for many small projects.

----------check.bat

```
@echo off

IF EXIST [\epoc32\include\domain\middleware\file_strange] GOTO NEW_API
GOTO OLD_API
GOTO :EOF

:NEW_API
echo.#define NEW_API_SUPPORTED>../inc/file_strange_supported.h
GOTO :EOF

:OLD_API
echo.#define OLD_API_SUPPORTED>../inc/file_strange_supported.h
GOTO :EOF
```

----------check.bat ends

**then i created a gnumake file**

----------checkmedialist.mk

```
do_nothing :
    @rem do_nothing

MAKMAKE : 
        check.bat

BLD : do_nothing

CLEAN : do_nothing

LIB : do_nothing

CLEANLIB : do_nothing

RESOURCE : do_nothing

FREEZE : do_nothing

SAVESPACE : do_nothing

RELEASABLES : do_nothing

FINAL : do_nothing
```

----------check.mk ends

**include the check.mk file in your bld.inf file, it MUST be before your MMP files**

```
PRJ_MMPFILES
gnumakefile checkmedialist.mk
```

**now at compile time the file `file_strange_supported.h` will have an appropriate flag set.
you can use this flag in your cpp files or even in the mmp file
for example in mmp**

```
#include "../inc/file_strange_supported.h"
#ifdef NEW_API_SUPPORTED
LIBRARY newapi.lib
#else
LIBRARY oldapi.lib
#endif
```

**and in .cpp**

```
#include "../inc/file_strange_supported.h"
#ifdef NEW_API_SUPPORTED
CStrangeApi* api = Api::NewLC();
#else
// ..
#endif
```