# Can the C preprocessor detect if a header file cannot be found and issue a specific warning?

Tags: include, c-preprocessor

I have a **C** file that needs a specific header file. If that header file does not exist, I want the preprocessor to issue a specific warning. Something like:

```
#if !(#include <special.h>)
#warning "Don't worry, you can fix this."
#warning "You just need to update this other repo over here:"
#endif
```

Is this possible with the **C** preprocessor?

Comment: It is possible in a makefile file.

Comment: you usually do that with a `./configure` script

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the C preprocessor be used to tell if a file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142877/can-the-c-preprocessor-be-used-to-tell-if-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always check if the `#define X` macro, from the included file, is ... defined :)

Comment: @asaelr Not sure if this is true for everyone, but in my build setup the PP/CC will bravely press on if it can't find an include file. So `#include <special.h>` followed by `#ifndef __SPECIAL_H__` works for me

Comment: If I have cross-platform code, I want to see if `platform-specific.h` exists before I import it. Using this approach with clang, I have to import it to see if something is defined, but if it doesn't exist, attempting to import it is a compiler/linker error

Comment: This won't work in all compilers because they'll fail the compile on the missing include.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is a old question, but I also needed a way to do this and I was disappointed when I read these answers. It turns out that clang has a nice `__has_include("header name")` directive that works flawlessly to do what you need :) 
Maybe you want to check if the directive is available first by calling `#if defined(__has_include)`

Comment: [gcc also has this](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html). It says gcc 5, but 4.9 seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not possible.  All you can do is try to `#include` the header, and if it doesn't exist, the compiler will give you an error.

An alternative would be to use a tool like [GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).  autoconf generates a shell script called `configure` which analyzes your build system and determines things like whether or not you have certain header files installed, and it generates a header file consisting of macros indicating that information.

For example, it might define `HAVE_SYS_TIME_H` if your build system includes the header `<sys/time.h>`, so you can then write code such as:

```
#if HAVE_SYS_TIME_H
#include <sys/time.h>
#else
#warning "Don't worry, you can fix this."
#endif
```

Comment: yepp, but it makes more sense to issue the warning/error from the configure script...

Answer (score -5):

If all you need is a warning that the header file is not there (and no custom code), then most compilers will already give you one.

```
$ LC_MESSAGES=en_US gcc -c bar.c
bar.c:1:17: fatal error: foo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: So, a fatal error and a warning are pretty much the same thing for you, aren't they?