# How to detect use_frameworks! at compile time

Tags: cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm developing a cocoapod. Someone who uses my pod can choose whether or not to include this line in their `Podfile`:

> `use_frameworks!`

If they include it, my code will be compiled into a `.framework` file. If not, it will be compiled into a `.a` file.

I'd like to use preprocessor macros to include different code in my cocoa pod, based on whether `use_frameworks!` is present.

For example, something like this:

```
#if PODFILE_CONTAINS_USE_FRAMEWORKS
@import My_Library;
#else
#import <My-Library/MyLibrary.h>
#end
```

This situation comes up when you have a pod name that's not `c99extidentifier` compliant.

I already tried checking for `#if defined COCOAPODS`, but that's defined in both these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working.

This snippet needs to go in the Podfile:

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            unless pi.podfile.defined_in_file.read().include? "\nuse_frameworks!\n"
              config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
              config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'NO_USE_FRAMEWORKS=1'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Then in the source file, the code looks like this:

```
#if defined NO_USE_FRAMEWORKS
#import <My-Library/MyLibrary.h>
#else
@import My_Library;
#endif
```

It defaults to `@import` syntax if the symbol is not present.

So the Podfile snippet only really needs to be added if `use_frameworks!` is not present. But it will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue as you had here.
I wanted to import Swift generated Header from Objective C within the same cocoapod, but the header is in different locations depending on the type of library (and therefore the presence or absence of use_frameworks!).
I've managed to import the correct file in both cases without having to change the Podfile.

---

#### What i did

In order to have the header imported in both static library (without use_frameworks!) and dynamic framework (with use_frameworks!) i used something i found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142877/can-the-c-preprocessor-be-used-to-tell-if-a-file-exists):

There basically is a compiler preprocessor macro `__has_include ( header-name )` to find out if it actually has an import file in that specific location.

So, in case the file is there, I use that import, otherwise I use the other one (assuming there is no third options).

So in my case the import look like this:

```
#if defined __has_include && __has_include(<MyLibrary-Swift.h>)
#import <MyLibrary-Swift.h>
#else
#import <MyLibrary/MyLibrary-Swift.h>
#endif
```

---

#### To run custom code according to the presence of `use_frameworks!`

In your case you can use the `__has_include(<MyLibrary-Swift.h>)` as a `podfile DOESN'T contain use_frameworks!` like this:

```
#if defined __has_include && __has_include(<MyLibrary-Swift.h>)
// use_frameworks! is NOT present
#else
// use_frameworks! is present
#endif
```

Assuming that the generated header will look like this:

- MyLibrary-Swift.h -> if use_frameworks! is NOT present in the podfile
- MyLibrary/MyLibrary-Swift.h -> if use_frameworks! is present in the podfile