# C++ try statement won't work with "#include"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++, dlib

My Dlib installation is in multiple places, so I'm writing a script that will search multiple locations for my necessary files to compile:

```
int main()
{
    try{
        #include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
        #include <dlib/image_io.h>
    }catch(...){
        cout << "Location A is incorrect: " << e << endl;
    }


    try{
        #include <dlib/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
        #include <dlib/dlib/image_io.h>
    }catch(...){
        cout << "Location B is incorrect: " << e << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason, `g++` still gives me the same `No such file...` error:

```
g++ IWillFindLib--00.cpp -o IWillFindLib--00.o
IWillFindLib--00.cpp:8:59: fatal error: dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h: No such file or directory
   #include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
                                                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Now, I know I could just add the locations with `g++ -I home/name/dlib`, but I want the finished project to run entirely hands-off with no input from the user. How can I make this work?

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can do something like this, but this is not one of them. You don't really give us a lot of information about the specifics of your problem, so it's hard to advise you on a sensible way to solve it. Maybe include a program (or script) that generates a header file with the necessary `#include`'s in it and have your code `#include` that file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the C preprocessor be used to tell if a file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142877/can-the-c-preprocessor-be-used-to-tell-if-a-file-exists)

Comment: Back from 2008?

Comment: You need to do this in the build scripts. The old way was autotools but now you'd be using cmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Err.  `try catch` happens at run time.  `#include` happens (very early) at compile time.  `#include` happens before you even really have a C or C++ compiler - it is just a fairly simple text processor at that point.

C++17 has [`__has_include`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) which does what you want - but you probably don't have a C++17 compiler.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260104/771073

Comment: Oh. So what should I do to check multiple places? There isn't any type of re-compile system I could set up is there?

Comment: @Rich: Read the other answers to that question.  (If you can rely on reasonably up-to date compilers (GCC5.x, MSVC2015, Clang), then it appears `__has_include` is supported.)

Comment: But how will I avoid "`No such file`" errors on different computers?

Comment: Look at the example at the bottom of the cppreference link.